# How to update table in redbeanphp

Tags: mysql, sql-update, redbean

Here is my function Insert.
What should i write after findOne to UPDATE the table. If field name exist update all other fields.

```
function insert_data_score($name, $clickcountscore, $levelofitems, $bonuscounter, $date, $timeofcasinobutton, $timeofcasinovideo){
$repeatChecker = R:: findOne('clicker', 'name = ?', array ($name));
if (isset($repeatChecker))
//  ????????
return " User $name exist";
$scoreboard = R::xdispense( 'clicker' );
$scoreboard->name = $name;
$scoreboard->clickcountscore = $clickcountscore;
$scoreboard->levelofitems = $levelofitems;
$scoreboard->bonuscounter = $bonuscounter;
$scoreboard->date = $date;
$scoreboard->timeofcasinobutton = $timeofcasinobutton;
R::store($scoreboard);
return "User: $name, created";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$repeatChecker->clickcountscore = $clickcountscore;
$repeatChecker->levelofitems = $levelofitems;
$repeatChecker->bonuscounter = $bonuscounter;
$repeatChecker->date = $date;
$repeatChecker->timeofcasinobutton = $timeofcasinobutton;
$repeatChecker->timeofcasinovideo = $timeofcasinovideo;
R::store($repeatChecker);
return " User $name Updated";
```

all wokrs if add this code after "if"